# Is it possible to import child yaml file in main yaml where child yaml will decrypt login info with ansible-vault

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-vault

**>>> **main.yaml****

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
     - child.yml
  tasks:
     - debug:
         var: username

     - name: Run Custom Module
       run_task:
         ip: "{{ ip }}"
         username: "{{ username }}"
         password: "{{ password }}"
       no_log: false
       register: result
```

**>>> child.yaml**

```yaml
---
- name: Child Playbook
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - secrets.txt
  vars:
    test_user: "{{ username }}"
```

**Note:**

`run_task` is custom module which accepts three parameters as input.
`secrets.txt` is ansible-vault encrypted file which contains one key-value pair: username, password

Command to run the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -vvvv main.yml --vault-password-file  ~/.vault_pass  -e 'ip=10.0.0.0'
```

I want to include this child yaml file where ever am using these credentials instead of repeating the code in main playbooks.

Comment: Are you trying to import a full playbook in the `vars_files` section of an other playbook? This will not work: a variable file top element must be a dictionnary (which keys are your varialbles), not a list (as a list of plays in a playbook) . Can you please edit your question and make it [mcve]((/help/mcve) with a complete sample of your variables, the result you get and a description of what you expect instead. As is, I personnaly don't understand what your are trying to do and which exact problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Yes @Zeitounator am trying to import the full playbook(child.yaml) in main playbook. I have tried this importing with "inlcude_vars" also instead of vars_files. Decrypted info  (in child.yaml) is not passing to main yaml.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html